# How to add white section between 2 sections on scroll - fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

So i finished my parallax and i would like to add a white empty section between each 2 sections that on scroll will get passed automaticaly like in [here](http://www.plasticbcn.com/en/).

On scroll, theres a white section that comes in and out fast. how can i do that?

Note: I am using fullpage.js for the parallax effect, [Check here.](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

HTML:

```
<div id="fullpage">
   <div class="section">Some section</div>
   <div class="section">Some section</div>
   <div class="section">Some section</div>
   <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

And Linking my header to the fullpage.js library make its work as a parallax so I cant really show the Javascript in place

Comment: wth is a parralax?

Comment: parallax* sorry its a typo

Comment: that...does not help.

Comment: check https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page2, thats the demo.

Comment: I would like to add that effect present in the link i added in my question. the white space effect between the sections

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).